# Silverlight + Wcf: CommunicationException : The remote server returned an error: Not Found

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have really strange problem. I load my silverlight application and if I call the service in lets say next 30 seconds (or lets say immediatelly) everything works. However if I call the service like 2 minutes after my application was loaded I will get

```
{System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at EnrollPortal.UI.SL.EnrollApp.FitC.FitCWatchlistMatcherClient.FitCWatchlistMatcherClientChannel.EndAssessBiometricQuality(IAsyncResult result)
   at EnrollPortal.UI.SL.EnrollApp.FitC.FitCWatchlistMatcherClient.EnrollPortal.UI.SL.EnrollApp.FitC.IFitCWatchlistMatcher.EndAssessBiometricQuality(IAsyncResult result)
   at EnrollPortal.UI.SL.EnrollApp.FitC.FitCWatchlistMatcherClient.OnEndAssessBiometricQuality(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)}
```

if i browse the service itself it is working.

Thanks for the hints!

Comment: Are you calling the service on load application..?

Comment: nope, really iam calling the service as a reaction on command, like user is going to upload something

Comment: Please post your web.config file..